# Finding a suitable comparison to find the limit of $(5n!+5)/(n^{100}+n!)$ as $n \to \infty $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling to find a suitable comparison for this limit. Could you help me out with your thought process?

Comment: What do you know about the factorial compared to $ n^{100} $?

Comment: **Clarification needed** : Is the numerator $5 \times (n!)$, or is the numerator $(5n)!~$?

Answer (score 0):

I would just rearrange a little,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{5!+5}{n^{100}+n!} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{5n!}{n^{100}+n!} + \frac{5}{n^{100}+n!}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{5n!}{n^{100}+n!} + \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{5}{n^{100}+n!}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{5}{n^{100}/n! + 1} + 0 \qquad\qquad \text{(divide by n! on top and bottom)}\\
&=  \frac{5}{0+1} = 5
\end{align*}
so that the limit is $5$. Nottice that I'm assuming your notation means $5(n!)$, and not $(5n)!$, and I'm also using that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{100}/n! = 0$, which you could use some easier test to prove.